# Bool & Bit Data Type, Exception Error When Updating & Saving Changes Into the Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a C#/WPF project using Entity Framework Core 5.0. I have a problem in retrieving and saving changes a record which has bool properties. Those bool values are saved as 'bit' data type in the SQL Server. See Below:

```
    Order orderItem = new Order();                        
    orderItem.IsVATIncluded = true;
    orderItem.IsBubbleWrapUsed = false;
    
    using(var db = new MyAppDbContext())
    {
         db.Orders.Add(orderItem);
         db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Following is the model definition of Order class:

```
   public class Order
   {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsVATIncluded { get; set; }
        public bool IsBubbleWrapUsed { get; set; }
   }
```

An Order record is read from the database to a corresponding datagrid, and then the Order record is popped up onto a dialog.

```
    private void ViewRecordButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Order orderRecord = (Order)OrderDataGrid.SelectedItem;
        OrderEntry dialog = new OrderEntry(_dbContext, orderRecord);
    }
```

Here's OrderEntry's XAML code:

```
    <CheckBox Content="Use Bubble Wrap" IsChecked="{Binding Path=OrderItem.IsBubbleWrapUsed}" />
    <CheckBox Content="VAT Included" IsChecked="{Binding Path=OrderItem.IsVATIncluded}" />
```

When the OK button of OrderEntry dialog is clicked, the changes in the Order record would be  persisted into the database. However, an exception error pops up when SaveChanges() is called.

```
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _dbContext.Orders.Update(OrderItem);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The exception error's message is as the following:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 4 ("@p0"): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.

The exception does NOT occur when the Order record's bool properties are not manually entered. That is, when those bool values are updated by the user through the dialog window's check boxes, such exception error does NOT occur when the record was retrieved later, changes updated, and saved onto the database. However, when those bool values are manually entered as above, the exception error pops up.

What is the problem?

Comment: It has to be something related to `Add` operation with `false` value in that property. Have you configured a default value for it (e.g. `HasDefaultValue` or `HasDefaultValueSql`)? Because there is a known issue with such properties (numeric with zero, bool with false etc. - the default for CLR type) not being sent for create command. Turn on EF Core logging with sensitive data option enabled and see the `INSERT` command issued by EF Core and its parameters/values.

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows that the database is expecting a float value, not a Boolean value. According to Microsoft booleans should be serialised as a bit value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

I suggest your underling database is therefore wrong, and you need to rebuild it, and change your float columns to the type 'bit'.